# Load (double) structured txt file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text

I try to load a public txt file into a dataframe in Pandas to execute a Name Entity recognition in the german language later. the original txt file has  the structure # words [date ] followed by a number (Position in the sentence), a word and the Name entitiy recognition  and the words are seperated with Tabs. So the structure is:

```
text [21-03-1991] 1 Aufgrund O O 2 des O O # text [22-04-1993] 1 Aber O P
```

has anyone an idea how can i get it into this format:

```
Aufgrund 0 0
des 0 0

Aber O P
```

best case every # in a new column?

i would like to use

```
pd.read_csv(...)
```

Comment: It is  going to be difficult  because the record specification  is not close to csv.   Further, it appears you wish to split a single read row into multiple labels in  the dataframe.  Will there be  spaces in the words?  Probably, although maybe that doesn't happen in German.     If this can be  done by pre-processing  the  file in or  outside of python, read_csv()  will work much better.

Comment: see my comment downstairs, i am close to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Text file example**

> ```
> text  [21-03-1991]    1   Aufgrund    O   O   2   des O   O   #   text    [22-04-1991]    1   Aber    O   P
> text  [21-04-1992]    2   Aufgrund    O   O   3   des O   O   #   text    [22-04-1992]    1   Aber    O   P
> text  [21-06-1993]    3   Aufgrund    O   O   5   des O   O   #   text    [22-04-1993]    1   Aber    O   P
> ```

```
import pandas as pd

# Reading tab separated text file
df = pd.read_csv("source.txt",sep='\t')

df1 = df.iloc[:,[3,4,5]]
df1.columns = ['V1','V2','V3']
df2 = df.iloc[:,[7,8,9]]
df2.columns = ['V1','V2','V3']
df3 = df.iloc[:,[14,15,16]]
df3.columns = ['V1','V2','V3']

d_one = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
final_df = d_one.append(df3, ignore_index=True)
print(final_df)
```

Comment: I did a similiar approach do this with the following code: `data = pd.read_csv('source.txt', sep='\t', header=None, encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` , now my outcome starts with # text [ ], and goes to the next column text O O

Comment: every # marks a new sentence, how can i sort it accordingly to this starting dataframe here: https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-and-classification-with-scikit-learn-f05372f07ba2

Comment: @PV8 Hi, I think your answer is in df3 dataframe in my code, Please check it once. Thank you

Comment: Not really, but i think i have it already! the shape is already matching for my starting point, i just need to write a loop over the indexes when I see a new `#`and then I have it. thx